# FileZilla doesn't connect to my XAMPP server?

Tags: ftp, filezilla, xampp

I have configured the XAMPP proftpd.conf file that look like this:

```
# This is a basic ProFTPD configuration file (rename it to
# 'proftpd.conf' for actual use.  It establishes a single server
# and a single anonymous login.  It assumes that you have a user/group
# "daemon" and "ftp" for normal operation and anon.

ServerName          "ProFTPD"
ServerType          standalone
DefaultServer           on

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                21
# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new dirs and files
# from being group and world writable.
Umask               022

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd)
MaxInstances            30

# Set the user and group that the server normally runs at.
User nobody
Group admin

# Normally, we want files to be overwriteable.
<Directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/*>
  AllowOverwrite        on
</Directory>

# only for the web servers content
DefaultRoot /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs

<Limit SITE_CHMOD>
  DenyAll
</Limit>

# daemon gets the password "xampp"
UserPassword nobody wRPBu8u4YP0CY

# daemon is no normal user so we have to allow users with no real shell
RequireValidShell off

# daemon may be in /etc/ftpusers so we also have to ignore this file
#to login with "OSX Users"
AuthPAM on
AuthPAMConfig ftpd
UseFtpUsers off
```

And I have configured FileZilla with this parameters:

```
user: nobody
pass: wRPBu8u4YP0CY
host: 192.168.1.17
port: 21
```

What's wrong with my parameters? I want to able my co-worker access my localhost via FTP

Comment: What's the error message in the FileZilla logs?

Comment: Stato:        Connessione a 192.168.1.17:21...
Stato:        Connessione stabilita, in attesa del messaggio di benvenuto...
Stato:        Server non sicuro, non supporta FTP su TLS.
Comando:  USER nobody
Risposta:   331 Password required for nobody
Comando:  PASS *************
Risposta:   530 Login incorrect.
Errore:       Errore critico: Impossibile collegarsi al server

Comment: I have changed the TLS config and now this error are solved, but why it report me the login are incorrect? It's not true, I have paste and copied perfectly..